# OpenVPN - Route and iptables configuration

Tags: openvpn

simplified network diagram:
[image: network diagram]

Certs and keys already created OK.
The 'straight' line between client and server is just to indicate a tunnel. Obviously, it goes through the firewall.

Client is windows or linux.
OpenVPN creates virtual interfaces on both machines, so I don't know which NAT perform on iptables and how to route from the virtual interface on the server to its local (192.168.100.3)

Can you guys help me on this one?

Comment: Could you clarify - what exactly do you want to get with openvpn?

Comment: Basically, the changes in iptables and route table. I think the config files are correct. Using tun, not tap.

Comment: I mean why do you need openvpn at all?